# Set the size of img before displaying

Tags: javascript, html

When user clicks on the button, the image from canvas will be displayed in a img element. I have checked to see if the width of image exceeds, if so, resize it before display. However, this does not work. When I debug it, I realized the checking of width is based on my old width and not the new width.

```
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadImage();" />
<img id="aImg" name="aImg" src="${param.src}"></img>
```

In Javascript...

```
function loadImage() {
    var dataURL = "http://xxx.jpg";
    var dis = document.getElementById("aImg");
    dis.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    dis.src = dataURL;

    if(dis.width > 800){
      dis.width = 800;
    }
}
```

My image is apparently over 800, however, it still displaying in its actual width. When I debug, `dis.width` actually check on my old width. Any ways to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Try creating a new image object from the url and getting the size from it.

Comment: I did but I am unable to retrieve the size out of the image object. `img.width` returns me `width()` instead of its actual width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it's `dis.style.width`, not `dis.width`

**edit**

Sorry, looks like I misunderstood your question. I think I would handle this in a different way, I would let the CSS handle the size of the image for me. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ysGVP/2/

Try adjusting my `max-width` value in my `.img-wrap` css.

When set at `100px` it shrinks the picture to fit the wrap, when set at say.. `900px`, the image is shown in its normal width. So basically, `max-width` can be used as your "if image is over X size, shrink it"

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but this will return `width' but not its actual width.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I misunderstood your question, I updated my post.

Comment: Actually what I want is to set a restriction to the size of image when display. I have tried `max-width` in my css, it works great now! Thanks so much. Have a nice day.